# Coin flip loop with specific number of heads

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, coin-flipping

My instructions: Write a program that “flips” a coin repeatedly and displays the results to the screen.
The program only stops when a specific # of heads has been flipped. That number of heads is specified by the user.
Your program should output the total number of flips made during execution.

My question is that I don’t know how long to generate Heads or Tails separately in a random manner. Im not sure how to incorporate a while or for loop in this or a counter either. Im very confused on what to do.

My code: (it’s botched because I really don’t know how what I should write)

```
import random

tails1= 0
heads= 1

heads_flips= int(input("Enter the amount of flips for heads:"))

while tails1 < heads_flips:
    if heads_flips > 0 print Heads amount of head_flips
    print("Heads", heads_flips)
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem, but considering you are a beginner.

```py
import random

tail = 0
head = 1

number_of_heads = 0
heads_flips= int(input("Enter the amount of flips for heads:"))


while number_of_heads < heads_flips:
    flip = random.randrange(2)
    if flip == head:
        number_of_heads += 1
    print("Heads", number_of_heads)
```

In essence, you are going to generate a random number, either 0 or 1 with `random.randrange(2)`. We have set that 0 will represent that it was tails and 1 that it was heads.

The variable `number_of_heads` is increased every time 1 was generated, and eventually, it will make the condition of our while loop becomes `False`.

Comment: @kora, would you mind upvoting/validating this answer?